# Amplify Federated Sign In not returning Email for Facebook getting attributes+required + email&error=invalid_request

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated-identity

I'm using AWS Amplify to add social signing.I am new to this. In my cognito user pool email attribute is required. So its not passing without the email. Below is the step by step API calls that happens in browser.

1 API call URL (GET)

> https://{baseURL}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.gosite.run%2Flogin
> &response_type=token&client_id={Id}&identity_provider=Facebook&scope=phone%20email%20profile%20openid%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&
> state={state}

2. From the response headers location we get the next URL (GET)

> [https://www.facebook.com/v6.0/dialog/oauth?client_id={id}&redirect_uri=https{url}.amazoncognito.com%2Foauth2%2Fidpresponse&scope=public_profile%2C+email&response_type=code&state={state}](https://www.facebook.com/v6.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7Bid%7D&redirect_uri=https%7Burl%7D.amazoncognito.com%2Foauth2%2Fidpresponse&scope=public_profile%2C+email&response_type=code&state=%7Bstate%7D)

3. From this response headers location goes the next URL (GET)

> https://{{baseURL}}/oauth2/idpresponse?code={{code}}&state={{state}}

And the response header location for this is

> https://{{baseURL}}/login#error_description=attributes+required%3A+%5Bemail%5D&state={{state}}&error=invalid_request

I'm not getting the email of the user. Can anyone help me know why? I have configured the aws congito like this.

[image: I have configured the aws congito like this]

And this is the code I used

```
<button onClick={() => handleFacebookLogin()} className="btn btn-xl btn-outline">
<span className="position-relative top-1">SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK</span>
```

```
  const handleFacebookLogin = async () => {
try {
  await Auth.federatedSignIn({
    provider: 'Facebook',
  })
} catch (e) {
  notification(e.message, "danger");
}
```

};

Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Seems like a quirky error, before getting too deep into it, you shouldn't be using implicit flow. Change the response type to code in your config. Shouldn't affect it but who knows, amplify is an undocumented mess.

Comment: @AndrewGillis Sorry!! Which one again? In the facebook url i.e. 2nd API call the response_type is code. Right?

Comment: nope your app to cognito should not be using implicit flow

Comment: @AndrewGillis Tried unchecking "Implicit grant" in cognito. Still getting the same issue

Comment: @HarisGeorge. Hi, do you found a solution? I am trying to add Facebook and I have everything working except that the email is not inside my Cognito attributes for the user. I have attribute mapping and everything setup. I also found a solution to create a custom button and add Auth.federatedSignIn({...'facebook'..}) to explicit call this flow, but it does not work either. Cognito user attribute is still with Sub and Identities (facebook profile data) and no email attribute.

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem for a while. I also tried unchecking 'Implicit grant', which is recommended, but the result did not change. I finally solved the problem. I forgot to add the `email` attribute to the authorized scope for my identity provider (in my case a custom identity provider with openid).